# Upload file input backbone.js

Tags: forms, backbone.js, file-upload, backbone-forms

im doing a form with Backbone-Form.js and i would like to know if are there any way to insert a input to upload file? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are supported in Backbone-Form

```
Text
Number
Password
TextArea
Checkbox
Checkboxes
Hidden
Select
Radio
Object
NestedModel
Date
DateTime
List
```

https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#schema-definition